# Product of Multivariate Normal Distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $p(x)=\mathcal{N}(x|\mu_x,\Sigma_x)$ and $p(y|x)=\mathcal{N}(y|Ax+b,\Sigma_y)$.

We want to compute $p(x,y)$. The book I'm reading says that
$$
\log p(x,y) = -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_x)^T \Sigma_x^{-1}(x-\mu_x)-\frac{1}{2}(y-Ax-b)^T\Sigma_y^{-1}(y-Ax-b)
$$
is clearly a joint Gaussian distribution, since it's a quadratic form.

However, to rewrite that expression in the form $-\frac{1}{2}(z-\mu_z)^T \Sigma_z^{-1}(z-\mu_z)$, the author ignores the linear and constant terms. The constant terms are not important because they end up in the normalization constant, but what about the linear terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Sigma_{z}$ depends only on $A$, $\Sigma_{x}$, and $\Sigma_{y}$.  It doesn't depend on $b$.  However, $\mu_{z}$ does depend on $b$, $y$, and $\mu_{x}$.

You haven't told us what source you're using, so it's difficult to say much more about this.